# MongoDB: Require that entire document is unique, while all the key-value pairs may not be unique in isolation

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance where each record has three key:value pairs. Each value from each pair may (and likely isn't) unique on it's own, but each document has a unique combination of all three values.

I have found information about how to enforce that *each* value for a certain key is unique, but I'm not sure how to require that the *aggregate* of three keys are unique, while allowing non-unique values for each sub-value.

Currently, I'm manually checking if a record exists before inserting it, which works but is rather slow:

```
if not coll.find({"basePath" : basePath, "internalPath" : internalPath, "itemhash" : itemhash}).count():
    coll.insert({"basePath" : basePath, "internalPath" : internalPath, "itemhash" : itemhash})
```

Gives me maybe ~200 inserts per second, even on a PC with a SSD.

Note that all three records have indexes, and I have no real idea what I'm doing, so everything is basically running the defaults after installing.

---

FWIW, I'm using PyMongo, and yes I have checked that I'm running the C extensions. I am.

---

**Edit:** So writing the question lead me to thing about what to call what I want to do better, which lead me to the `unique` kwarg for `create_index`. However, setting `coll.ensure_index([("basePath", ASCENDING), ("internalPath", ASCENDING), ("itemhash", ASCENDING)], unique=True, drop_dups=True)` does not seem to actually ensure the uniqueness of each record.

---

Further Edit:

Ok, I think I'm getting somewhere. the key seems to be compound indexes, but things were obsured by the fact that my collection is not named `collection`, but `deduper_collection` (apparently just referring to a aspect of the `db` object creates a collection named as the aspect you refer to):

```
def go():
    client = MongoClient()
    print client
    db = client.deduper_database
    print db
    coll = db.deduper_collection
    print coll

    coll.ensure_index([("basePath", ASCENDING), ("internalPath", ASCENDING), ("itemhash", ASCENDING)], unique=True, dropDups=True)
    print "Records = ", coll.count()
```

It's currently stuck at ensure_index with `mongod` using 100% CPU, so I assume it's doing something related to index building.

---

Ok, record count dropped from 6772754 to 6765917, so I think the duplicates that got added when I was trying to determine if `unique=True` was being enforced (it was not - whoops) have been purged properly.

Aaaand it now throws `pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError` when I try to insert a duplicate. Success!

@mnemosyn's answer got me there, but that answer in syntax that `PyMongo` will accept is:

```
coll.ensure_index([("basePath", ASCENDING), 
                   ("internalPath", ASCENDING), 
                   ("itemhash", ASCENDING)], 
                   unique=True, dropDups=True)
```

The critical thing being `unique=True`.

`dropDups=True` *can* potentially **delete data**, but in my particular case, where I know what my DB structure *should* look like, it just served to clear out the accidental inserts that happened when I was trying to test `unique=True` when it was not being enforced properly.

Comment: Be aware that a compound key value like all indexed values must be less than 1024 bytes or it is skipped. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [compound key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-indexes), and they can be made unique as well:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { basePath: 1, internalPath: 1, itemhash : 1}, 
                           { unique: true } )
```

Comment: I'm trying that (see edit), and it's not working, or I have the syntax wrong for pymongo.

Comment: Yeah, bad timing. But then, please describe what the actual problem is. What is the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()`? Did you try it from the mongo console rather than through PyMongo?

Comment: `db.collection.getIndexes()` returns `[ ]`. I'm trying it from the console now, though I'd like to be able to do all the DB setup through python eventually.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting inserts even when I've created a compound-index as described in your answer via the console, and it shows up in `db.collection.getIndexes()`.

Comment: @FakeName It might be easier for everyone if you edit your question with the .getIndexes() output and also show what you are inserting. This answer could probably do with examples as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I'm working at that as I go. For one, it turns out the relevant collection isn't `db.collection`, but `db.deduper_collection`, since it's apparently named by some of the python code (and the tool I'm writing managed deduplicating things).

Comment: Basically, just writing the question put me on the trail of a bundle of ideas. I'm puzzling things out further currently.

Comment: whatever I just did, `mongod` is slammed at 100% CPU. I think it's building the index.

Comment: I don't know why, but I dropped my indexes, rebuilt them, and now it's working.

Comment: I just can't shake the feeling that some of those 'tools' make things more complicated, harder to debug and a lot slower...

Answer (score 0):

You could use unique compound index. In mongo shell it is looks like:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "basePath": 1, "internalPath": 1, "itemhash": 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

These indexes enforce uniqueness for the combination of index keys and not for either key individually.
Also, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-indexes

Comment: I'm using `coll.ensure_index([("basePath", ASCENDING), ("internalPath", ASCENDING), ("itemhash", ASCENDING)], unique=True, dropDups=True)` (via pyMongo), and it's not working.

Comment: May be try `coll.create_index([("basePath", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("internalPath", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("itemhash", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True, dropDups=True)`

Comment: Yep. Somehow, that wasn't working before, I dropped all my indexes, rebuilt, and now it's working.

Comment: -1: exact copy of my answer, save for the quotation marks and `dropDups`. even the same link.